# ADO.NET tableadapter add/update/delete

Tags: c#, tableadapter

I'm using the table adapter in C# where visual studio generates the code for you.
I have inserts and updates working just fine using the following code.

However when trying to delete using the .update it gives me the following error.

> Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows.

```
this.workersTableAdapter.Update(this.nursery_dbDataSet_workers.workers);
```

Comment: Do you have a delete command specified on the adapter...?

Comment: where would I find that?

Comment: I do not have a .delete from the workersTableAdapter

Answer (score 1):

Open the DataSet designer and click on the Adapter. In the properties windows it has 4 Command properties, check the **DeleteCommand**.  It seems to be missing.

You cam rerun the wizard or write the Delete Sql by hand.

Comment: The checkbox for Enable Delete is checked but I don't know where it put the code.  I even ran through the wizard again and it said that it created the delete statement.

Comment: My answer above tells you how to find the Delete statement. Hit the little [...] button at the end.

Comment: Further note: 'Enable Delete' is not a property on a TableAdapter. Read carefully, it's not the Forms designer you need here.